# Javascript logical operators and assignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

```
x = 1 || 2;
alert(x);
x = undefined || 2;
alert(x);
```

Apparently `x` in the above code doesn't return a boolean value.  It returns the first valid value, which is 1 in the first case and 2 in the second case.

Is there any other strangeness like this I should watch out for?

Comment: this question is too broad, for JavaScript is full of interesting behavior, due to its type system and other design principles. For example, try to add two integers that are held in strings var ```a ="1"``` and ```var b ="2"```. ```var c =  a +b ``` will be ```"12"```, not ```3```

Comment: when you put js expressions in if(expression) it is evaluated as if !!<expresion> double not. All values in if/while will give you boolean say if(1||2) > true and x = 1||2 will store x= 1,

Comment: The behavior of logical OR operator is not a "strangeness", it's [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) ...

Comment: All variables in javascript are "truthy" or "falsy", regardless of whether they are actual booleans.

Comment: The definition of "strangeness" is "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: Just wait when you're getting to logical AND, it returns the first operand if it can be evaluated to falsy, otherwise, the second operand.

Comment: Teemu, that's really what && does? edit: Oh my goodness, who designed this language?  They should be fired or forced to develop WASM

Comment: Yeah, logical operators in JS are returning operands, not booleans.

Comment: Ok, well this was exactly what I wanted to understand.  So all logical operators return operands and conditional expressions (as in if/else/while/for) return !!(expression)?

Comment: Yep, but that expression is evaluated to truthy/falsy by a loop "operator". Please don't forget, that JS is a weakly typed language, and this arragement is needed in a case when you're comparing two operands of different types. To preserve consistency, it's natural to work like this also with two operands of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator in Javascript as in `x || y` will evaluate to the first operands if it is truthy or the second operand if the first one is not truthy.  It is [documented on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description).

`truthy` in Javascript is described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).  It's basically, anything except one of the `falsey` values which are:

```
false
null
undefined
0
NaN
""
```

So, you have to think of the `||` operator as something that deals in truthy/falsey, not in pure Booleans.

The operator works as it has been specified and hundreds of thousands of developers have learned it that way and successfully use it.  It is not a pure Boolean operator.  It does not necessarily return a Boolean value.  That is different than some other languages.  If you want to call different "strange", you're welcome to your opinion.  But, it is what it is and it has always been this way in Javascript.

It's easy to learn what it does and use it for that.  There is no real strangeness or unpredictability to its specification or implementation once you understand the design intent.

It is different than some people coming from other languages might expect, but that is not the goal of really any language.  Each language has it's own design that must be learned to use it appropriately.

Comment: Ok, and what about && does it evaluate to the union of two truthy values? i.e. [1, 2, 3] and [2, 3] == [2, 3]?

Comment: @veta - `&&` is explained [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description).  Quoting from that: *Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.  Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.*